# How do I run my version of Python (3.7.5) with Homebrew, on MacBook that already has Python (3.7.3) installed natively

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, macos-catalina

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

I've installed Python3 on my MacBook using Homebrew. This is so I can access the latest version (3.7.5).

However I've recently updated to Catalina, which already has Python3 installed (3.7.3).

The problem is, when I type "python3" into the Command Line, it starts the MacOS version of Python (3.7.3) not the latest version I've installed using Homebrew.

Is there a way I can make sure I'm always accessing my dev/Homebrew version of Python?

Comment: This is a bit off-topic for stackoverflow, maybe instead try superuser?

Comment: No reason to care, unless a bug fixed since 3.7.3 was blocking you.  They will be for all practical purposes the same.

Comment: Are you using `zsh` now instead of `bash`? It sounds like you need to update your shell configuration to make sure `/usr/local/bin` appears in your `PATH` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I will re-post in SuperUser.

Comment: Re. the difference between 3.7.3 and 3.7.5, I was more concerned that when I start installing other packages (e.g. pip3 install pipenv then pipenv install django==2.2.0) those packages won't be installed alongside my homebrew version of Python (3.7.5) but the native macOS version of Python (3.7.3). Could this cause issues with debugging?

Comment: When you type `python3` it looks at each directory in your PATH and runs the first one that matches. Apple usually puts its stuff in `/usr/bin`. **homebrew** puts its in `/usr/local/bin`. So, set your PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` is **before** `/usr/bin` and you will pick up **homebrew** programs instead of Apple ones. You can see how the shell is going to interpret something if you use the `type` command, e.g. `type python` or `type python3`